# How to automate Intellij project configuration

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, ant, perforce

I have the use case where I have several projects (several product versions), and I want to automate the project setup for me and my team.

Is there a way to programmatically setup an Intellij project by using some Intellij API(Intellij plugin / shell script)?

For example:
Set run configuration with tomcat with different versions,
Maven configuration,
Perforce configuration

I know that I can manipulate .xml files in the project / Intellij but it feels dirty...

Comment: Manipulating xml files is actually gonna be much cleaner than some sort of UI macro'ing, or whatever you're thinking.

If you really want to write your own plugin for it, you can use the intellij API.. http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/welcome.html

Answer (score 0):

You can share run configurations with team members easily. When you go to Run Configurations, beside the box where you enter the configuration name, tick the box labelled `Share`.

Then look in your .idea project folder for the folder `runConfigurations`. Here you will find xml files for each of the run configurations you have made. Share this directory with your colleagues, when they reimport the project, they can add the `runConfigurations` folder to their `.idea` folder and the configurations will load for use.

Comment: Well that's nice, but I'm aiming for some API which allows me to perform all GUI actions using a script. For example - configure tomcat with deployment artifacts, then define maven version, configure project JDK and so on.

Comment: I am also trying to achieve this, as we use nearly identical settings for many parallel projects, but have to update them each time we switch.